# I want the following results from python tuple addition

Tags: python, tuples

python code

```
test_1 = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
test_2 = (("A", "B"), ("C", "D", "E"))
test_3 = test_1 + test_2
print(test_3)
```

I would like to obtain the following results

```
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'E'))
```

However the results are as follows.
How should I write this?

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', ('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'E'))
```

Comment: `(test_1,) + test_2` or `(test_1, *test_2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `,` because when you are adding it takes the second tuple and puts it into the first. But, when you use `,` its test `t_3` to `test_1` and `test_2`. The `*` shows that it is an arg.

```py
test_1 = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
test_2 = ("A", "B"), ("C", "D", "E")
t_3 = (test_1, *test_2)

print(t_3)
```